# Android PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder how to avoid double scheduling?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm using the new WorkManager, and was wondering, when I schedule a Periodic work, how can I avoid re-schedule it, is it automatically handled by OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to check already running work manager just because you don't want duplicate works. You can simply use [enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest))

> This method allows you to enqueue a uniquely-named
>   PeriodicWorkRequest, where only one PeriodicWorkRequest of a
>   particular name can be active at a time. For example, you may only
>   want one sync operation to be active. If there is one pending, you can
>   choose to let it run or replace it with your new work.

So you don't need to worry about duplicacy about works.

```
 workmanager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP , photoCheckWork);
```

- Where TAG is unique name by which work manager will check duplicacy.
- You can [choose between](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy) `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` and `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a periodic Worker, so it handles rescheduling the next occurrence automatically.
To avoid that it is re-scheduled, you can return Result.failed() from your Worker or you can cancel the `WorkRequest` from your app. In this case you should handle cancellation inside your `Worker` as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work).